# After I changed 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' I started getting 3 distinct new errors

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, parameters, deprecated

The 3 new errors are:

Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.

Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match

Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class

This started when I got the original error of:
Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

I followed the advice of

[Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749767/error-the-method-inheritfromwidgetofexacttype-isnt-defined-for-the-class-bu)

and changed it to dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.

However, the ONLY place I found this in was in my native_device_orientation.dart file.  I used Visual Studio Code's search function and could not find any use of 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' .

I've done:

**flutter clean**

**flutter pub get**

**flutter downgrade**

**flutter upgrade**

I've even changed the channel; currently I'm using 'master'

All in various combinations.

The entirety of my error is listed below:

```
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.4/lib/src/popupMenu.dart:611:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
      theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:106:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.4/lib/src/selectDialog.dart:153:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'child'.        
      child: AlertDialog(
      ^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart:1065:12: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<T?> showDialog<T>({
           ^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);  
                        ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
 - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.    
 - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.        
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.        
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.       
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.        
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
      ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.  
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'. - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.     
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.     
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'. - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.    
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.    
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'. - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'. - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'. - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'. - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.   
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.        
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.        
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
 - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.     
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1029

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        17.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

UPDATE: March 20, 2021

I ran the following:

**flutter pub upgrade**

**flutter pub outdated**

**flutter pub upgrade --major-versions**

Now I'm getting :

```
rror: Error when reading '/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera_camera-2.0.0/lib/page/camera.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:camera_camera/page/camera.dart';
       ^
lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:15:10: Error: Type 'FirebaseUser' not found.
  Future<FirebaseUser> get currentUser async => _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/repositories/firestore_repository.dart:14:3: Error: Type 'Firestore' not found.
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

There are a bunch of other errors but they're mostly about Firestore not found.

Answer (score 9):

1- Update all plugins or use the word '**any**' instead of the plugin version , like this:

```
#shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
shared_preferences: any
```

2- Override path_provider , Copy these lines to **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependency_overrides:
  # Override path_provider to pick up fixes for FFI changes.
  path_provider: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
```

3- run these commands :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

more info:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76129

Comment: I get a bunch of errors.  The most prominent of which is the shadowThemeOnly

```
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.4/lib/src/popupMenu.dart:611:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
      theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
```

Comment: Sorry.  I should mention more specifically that I DID follow the instructions mentioned by dev001 but it resulted in that shadowThemeOnly error again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will fix the problem:

Add to folder pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  ffi: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a cache-related issue.

Delete the following:

- .idea
- build
- pubspec-lock

Then run:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error, then I updated SDK in pubspec.yaml to make it null safe. Also updated the null safe plugins.

Now, it is running

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may use libraries that do not apply to your sdk.
In my case, my flutter version was 2.2.0 and there was a library that did not support this version and I reduced my sdk flutter from 2.2.0 to 2.0.6 and the problem was solved

Comment: Hello!

Thank you for the reply!

I went through the downgrades but it either did not work or impacted other areas of my app.

I'll keep testing things out since I'm getting different results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade you dependancies, This solution worked for me:
`flutter pub upgrade`